What would the Signal to noise ratio be for SSB under normally (just) readable conditions?
I want to estimate an upper limit for the data that can be sent over single side band.
The upper limit can be determined using Shannon-Hartley theory.
The Shannon-Hartley theorem is given by:
$$C = B \log_2 \left( 1 + \frac{S}{N} \right)$$
For this we require the bandwidth B in Hz, in this case ~3000Hz and the Signal to noise ratio S/N in power.
To convert the signal-to-noise ratio (SNR) from decibels (dB) to the linear form needed, we can use the following formula:
$$
\frac{S}{N} = 10^{\left(\frac{\text{SNR (dB)}}{10}\right)}
$$
If we are reading voice at say 3 and 1 "Readable with considerable difficulty" and "Faint signals, barely perceptible". What might the implied Signal to noise ratio, be for that?
I might hazard 2dB. In which case, using the formula above I can calculate the limit as ~4116 bps
So, what might the true signal to noise ratio be for an SSB signal reported to be 3 and 1.
If the answer is "It depends". Great! Tell us what it depends on, and give the answer for some likely scenarios!

definitely worth checking out this answer to How big is a decibel, as well as this q&a re FT8 SNR calculation. these don't directly answer your question, but provide some tangential elucidation.
